# Why Impala not working on hbase table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, cloudera, impala

I create an external table B of hbase table A using hive. I can successfully access the data of B.Then I followed the official guide to type in Imapla Shell:

```
invalidate metadata B;
```

And then I query this external table B in Impala Shell:

```
select * from B limit 4;
```

but it outputs:

```
ERROR: RuntimeException: couldn't retrieve HBase table (mv_p2pusers) info:
Enable/Disable failed
```

Here are some logs related:

```
11:13:58.937 AM INFO    jni-util.cc:177 
java.lang.RuntimeException: couldn't retrieve HBase table (mv_p2pusers) info:
Enable/Disable failed
    at com.cloudera.impala.planner.HBaseScanNode.computeScanRangeLocations(HBaseScanNode.java:300)
    at com.cloudera.impala.planner.HBaseScanNode.init(HBaseScanNode.java:125)
    at com.cloudera.impala.planner.SingleNodePlanner.createScanNode(SingleNodePlanner.java:891)
    at com.cloudera.impala.planner.SingleNodePlanner.createTableRefNode(SingleNodePlanner.java:1082)
    at com.cloudera.impala.planner.SingleNodePlanner.createSelectPlan(SingleNodePlanner.java:526)
    at com.cloudera.impala.planner.SingleNodePlanner.createQueryPlan(SingleNodePlanner.java:151)
    at com.cloudera.impala.planner.SingleNodePlanner.createSingleNodePlan(SingleNodePlanner.java:117)
    at com.cloudera.impala.planner.Planner.createPlan(Planner.java:47)
    at com.cloudera.impala.service.Frontend.createExecRequest(Frontend.java:842)
    at com.cloudera.impala.service.JniFrontend.createExecRequest(JniFrontend.java:146)
11:13:58.939 AM INFO    status.cc:114   
RuntimeException: couldn't retrieve HBase table (mv_p2pusers) info:
Enable/Disable failed
    @           0x78b793  (unknown)
    @           0xa68275  (unknown)
    @           0x9802c6  (unknown)
    @           0x99db78  (unknown)
    @           0x99e6e4  (unknown)
    @           0x9d50cb  (unknown)
    @           0xb33687  (unknown)
    @           0xb29054  (unknown)
    @           0x9ac52b  (unknown)
    @          0x1571c39  (unknown)
    @          0x155d9cf  (unknown)
    @          0x155f914  (unknown)
    @           0x92d363  (unknown)
    @           0x92daca  (unknown)
    @           0xaa4faa  (unknown)
    @           0xaa7130  (unknown)
    @           0xca79b3  (unknown)
    @       0x386be079d1  (unknown)
    @       0x386bae8b6d  (unknown)
11:13:58.940 AM INFO    impala-server.cc:824    
UnregisterQuery(): query_id=d4269ff898eb4e7:1866144af0d14a7
11:13:58.940 AM INFO    impala-server.cc:893    
Cancel(): query_id=d4269ff898eb4e7:1866144af0d14a7
11:13:59.935 AM INFO    ClientCnxn.java:975 
Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
11:13:59.935 AM WARN    ClientCnxn.java:1102    
Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
Java exception follows:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
11:14:01.036 AM INFO    ClientCnxn.java:975 
Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
11:14:01.037 AM WARN    ClientCnxn.java:1102    
Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
Java exception follows:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
11:14:02.138 AM INFO    ClientCnxn.java:975 
Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
11:14:02.138 AM WARN    ClientCnxn.java:1102    
Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
Java exception follows:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
11:14:02.199 AM INFO    impala-hs2-server.cc:795    
GetSchemas(): request=TGetSchemasReq {
  01: sessionHandle (struct) = TSessionHandle {
    01: sessionId (struct) = THandleIdentifier {
      01: guid (string) = "\xf8\xb9n\xe4\xb4\xf6N\xef\xad)9W.\x92#Y",
      02: secret (string) = "\xc0?\xc7\xd9\x930C\x9b\xb5\xf6K\x8em\xcb\xf8\xe4",
    },
  },
}
11:14:02.203 AM INFO    MetadataOp.java:414 
Returning 19 schemas
```

It seems the hbase table B is either enabled nor disabled,very strange.I googled around,Is this related to the hbase security issues or the impala version problem?

Did anybody encountered the same problems?How to solve this?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Enable HBase service from Impala Configuration.

You can do it from Cloudera manager, Imapala->configuration 
search from "Hbase" and enable the service.
PFA.
[image]